# 3D plot of Excel data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to recreate this plot using some of my own excel data but I've hit a wall. So far I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/data.xlsx')

yr = df['Year']
jd = df['Jday']
dc = df['Discharge']

x = np.asarray(yr)
y = np.asarray(jd)
z = np.asarray(dc)

X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap='autumn')

ax.set_xlabel("Year")
ax.set_ylabel("Jday")
ax.set_zlabel("Discharge")


plt.show()
```

But when I run this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap='autumn')
  File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 412, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1581, in plot_surface
    raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I changed my code to:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/data.xlsx')

yr = df['Year']
jd = df['Jday']
dc = df['Discharge']

X = np.asarray(yr).reshape(-1,2)
Y = np.asarray(jd).reshape(-1,2)
Z = np.asarray(dc).reshape(-1,2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('seismic')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,
                       cmap = my_cmap,
                       edgecolor = 'none')
fig.colorbar(surf, ax=ax,
             shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)

plt.show()
```

When I run this it produces the following plot:
[image]

Which obviously doesn't match the other plot. It seems to be plotting the data from each year in a single line instead of creating filled in polygons which is what I think it's supposed to do. I have a feeling this issue has to do with the `.reshape` function but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Your error message is clear. Z must be 2-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Note: original answer completely rewritten!

The problem is, as your data stated, that the Z-argument must be two-dimensional. In your problem, you don't need `np.meshgrid` at all. This is typically used to make a 'grid' of all possible combinations of X/Y, after which you can use these combinations to calculate your response matrix `Z`. However, since all your data is read in, it is merely a reshaping of all 1d-arrays to 2d-arrays:

```py
target_shape = (np.sqrt(X.shape[0]),-1)
X = np.reshape(X, target_shape)
Y = np.reshape(Y, target_shape)
Z = np.reshape(Z, target_shape)
```

Have a look at the documentation of [np.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) for some more information.

Comment: When I try this I get         return bound(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 366 into shape (366,366)

Comment: You are correct that my answer didn't work in your case. I have completely revised my answer. Have a look if it works now

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, when I try this solution I get a TypeErorr: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. When I print(np.dtype(x)) it comes back as int64. I've tried to do x.astype(int) but I get the same error.

Comment: I suspect the trouble begins in the `target_shape` line? What you could do is just set the number yourself (I just used np.sqrt as this would probably render a nice square matrix, but offcourse you can do what you want here). with the second value -1, it will automatically adapt the shape such that all elements fit in the reshape